# bash - command in a variable - issue with quotes

Tags: bash, variables

I want to store the date of last Sunday in a variable.

```
#/bin/bash

OFFSET=$(date +%u)
COMMAND="date --date='"$((OFFSET))" days ago' +%Y%m%d"
DATEFULL=$($COMMAND)

echo offset $OFFSET
echo command $COMMAND
echo datefull $DATEFULL
```

Output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ./test.sh
date: extra operand ‘ago'’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
offset 1
command date --date='1 days ago' +%Y%m%d
datefull
```

Pasting the result of $COMMAND in command line gives the right result:

```
[root@localhost ~]# date --date='1 days ago' +%Y%m%d
20210822
```

So why does he claim about "date: extra operand ‘ago'’" ? How can I execute the result of command and set it in a variable?

Comment: Don't put commands in variables, they're for data, not executable code. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure why this doesn't work. I think it has something to do with bash parsing quotes out of the command. If you use `eval`, it works:

```sh
#/bin/bash

OFFSET=$(date +%u)
COMMAND="date --date='"$((OFFSET))" days ago' +%Y%m%d"
DATEFULL=$(eval "$COMMAND")

echo offset $OFFSET
echo command $COMMAND
echo datefull $DATEFULL
```

Output

```
$ OFFSET=$(date +%u)
$ COMMAND="date --date='"$((OFFSET))" days ago' +%Y%m%d"
$ DATEFULL=$(eval "$COMMAND")
$ echo offset $OFFSET
offset 1
$ echo command $COMMAND
command date --date='1 days ago' +%Y%m%d
$ echo datefull $DATEFULL
datefull 20210822
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use arrays for commands, instead of variables :

```
#!/bin/bash

OFFSET=$(date +%u)
COMMAND=(date "--date=$OFFSET days ago" +%Y%m%d)
DATEFULL=$("${COMMAND[@]}")

echo offset $OFFSET
echo command $COMMAND
echo datefull $DATEFULL
```

Also all uppercase variable names can cause clashes with bash-defined variables.